# Code in original form

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have HTML code for a table in database. I want to present that code in its original form in a textarea so that I can make changes in it. When I echo it appears in compiled form (table), not in original HTML code. How can I display its original HTML code?

```
<textarea rows="40" cols="30" name="content" id="content">                
    <?php  echo '<pre>'.$row['content'].'</pre>'; ?>                
</textarea>
```

Comment: You mean it outputs as the source code and not the rendered HTML? If so you'll need a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: No Sir, it outputs as rendered HTML and I want to output it as Code

Comment: I don't see how it would do that, https://jsfiddle.net/9y00ocm7/.

Comment: @MianSaeedAkbar Try my answer

Comment: @BasheerAhmed see the OP's answer below, he/she was using `tinymce`. HTML doesn't render as such in a textarea by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<code>` tag to achieve this.

Comment: you can use <textarea rows="40" cols="30" name="content" id="content">                
    <?php  echo '<code>'.$row['content'].'</code>'; ?>                
</textarea>

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing  `<` by `&lt;`

```
<?php  echo '<pre>'.str_replace('<', '&lt;',$row['content']).'</pre>'; ?>
```